# Net unrealized appreciation only applies to pre-tax 401k?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, ira

I just want to confirm that NUA only applies to pre-tax 401k because a post-tax 401k/ira doesn't have any taxes for withdrawals. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. [NUA treatment](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/personal-finance/retirement/company-stock) minimizes taxes on in-kind withdrawals from traditional retirement accounts. But in-kind qualified withdrawals from Roth accounts do not need any treatment because they [are not taxed](https://www.mysolo401k.net/ira-llc-owned-real-estate-in-kind-distribution-rules/).